# How to visualize PointCloud2 in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a BAG file, XXX.bag

I started `roscore` and `rosbag play XXX.bag`. Then I opened `rviz`.

I added a `PointCloud2`

But I got an error
`Transform[sender=unknow] For frame [velodyne] fixed frame [map] doesn't exist`

My global options has fixed frame `map`

I am new to ROS. I don't understand any of these error messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257942/how-to-visualize-pointcloud2-in-rviz/) by [Albertx](https://answers.ros.org/users/29836/albertx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that you have left the fixed frame to `map`. RViz doesn't know where to place the point cloud, since the `map -> velodyne` transform doesn't exist. So, either use the static_transform_publisher in tf to publish that transform, or just change the frame in rviz to `velodyne`.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) with karma: 366 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change the RViz fixed frame to the frame of the pointcloud.

You can find the frame of the pointcould  with:

```
rostopic echo -n 1 POINTCLOUD_TOPIC | grep frame_id
```

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1